# How to let a specific android device (fonepad) use different layout folder

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm working on an Android app that has different layouts for phones (designed for portrait) and for tablets (designed for landscape).

Now I want to support the Asus Fonepad as a phone but since it has the size and resolution of a 7 inch tablet it always uses the layouts in the layout-sw600dp folder. But the fonepad understands itself as a phone and shows the fullscreen text edit window whenever text input is used in landscape.

How can I make this device use layouts and values from the phones and not from the -sw600dp folders? Is this even possible?

Comment: Hmm interesting. So when you 'detach' the Phone from the larger Tablet screen, it still think it has this large screen?

Comment: try giving folder name wrt resolution, e.g. layout-480x800

Comment: Stefan, no, this is about the fonepad, not the padfone. :) the fonepad is a 7" smartphone with a resolution of 800x1280.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can inflate the layout by java code when the app is running in the Asus Fonepad.